# When using Riverpod StateNotifier, the state is not updating properly, so the ui and the widget is not being rebuilt

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, riverpod

When reordering a ReorderableListView, the method reorderIntervals:

```
void reorderIntervals(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
    if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
      newIndex -= 1;
    }
    final ListItem item = _intervals.removeAt(oldIndex);
    _intervals.insert(newIndex, item);
    state = [..._intervals];
  }
```

gets called, and it works properly the issue is that even though the state is changed, the ui/ widget is not being rebuilt so the change does not appear in the ReordableListView widget until I perform a hot reload.

This is the ReorderableListView:

```
ReorderableListView(
                            onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                              intervalList.reorderIntervals(oldIndex, newIndex);
                            },
                            children: intervalList.intervals.map(
                              (item) {
                                return IntervalTile(
                                  key: Key(item.id.toString()),
                                  interval: item,
                                  intervalList: intervalList,
                                  singleInterval:
                                      item is SingleInterval ? item : null,
                                  groupInterval:
                                      item is GroupInterval ? item : null,
                                  index: intervalList.intervals.indexOf(item),
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          ),
```

It is also wrapped by a consumer widget.

```
Consumer(
      builder: (context, ref, child) {
        return SafeArea(
```

It is inside this class:

```
final intervalListProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<IntervalList, List<ListItem>>(
  (ref) {
    return IntervalList();
  },
);

class IntervalListView extends ConsumerWidget {
  const IntervalListView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

And it is calling the method in this other class:

```
class IntervalList extends StateNotifier<List<ListItem>> {
  late Future<void> existingIntervalsFuture;
  final TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  IntervalList() : super([]) {
    _intervals = [];
  }
  List<ListItem> _intervals = [];
```

The feature used to worked with provider, but when i changed it to riverpod, it stopped working cause I changed the classes from a Statefulwidget, to a ComsumerWidget, and the IntervalList class from a ChangeNotifier to a StateNotifier

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this:

```
StateNotifier<List<ListItem>>
```

because a `List` does not have a useful-to-Riverpod override for `==`. You should construct a class that holds the list that is *immutable*.

But more importantly, stop using StateNotifier! The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Can I ask you a question? What can I do with StreamProvider , I don't find any real case to use with it.

Comment: You'd use it with a natural Stream, like the userAuthChanges with Firebase.  Creating a StreamProvider from that stream ensures that the most recent event is always available instantly, followed by notifications of later events.

Comment: This was my issue! I also had a `build` method on my `Notifier` which initialises the list to empty. That is fine, but it was being rebuilt when it shouldn't have been because it was `AutoDispose`. So I had to also make it `keepAlive`. I could probably also utilise `watch` in the correct parent widget to ensure it is not disposed of and rebuilt unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

1: if you are using the ConsumerWidget you don't have to use Consumer in the builder.

2: load the stateprovider in the setstate

3: add the reorderIntervals method in the stateprovider to call the stateprovider when executing the method